# how to calculate the height of a div with some text inside and a fixed width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following code:

```
<div class="content">
                        <a href="/profile/Nat's Rare &amp; Raw" class="link-name"><strong>Irene Natalia</strong></a>
                        Hooray! we'll proceed with the shipping and inform the tracking # tomorrow :) Thank you, Angel! :)

                        <br>
                        <span class="date">7 days ago</span>
                    </div>
```

I wanted to know the height of this div from using javascript. Is there a way to do so?
This div has a fixed sized width (in this case 150px). I just wanted to know the height of the div say the text changed. Preferred method is via jQuery but javascript is fine as well

**EDIT:**

A very important note here is that this is a calculation before the div is being rendered. I am basically creating a pinterest layout and I need to calculate the height of the comments in the item card so that masonry can lay it out first before the image is loaded.

Comment: Have you tried searching the jQuery Docs? They have all the functions that you can use clearly explained with examples and everything, how about that?

Comment: The issue is that this is before the view is rendered, so the element doesn't exist yet, a.k.a: the div is not there. So all I have is a text.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Javascript:**

```
element.offsetHeight;
```

This gives the height of an element

See about [offsetHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.offsetHeight) here and this is pure javascript.

**jQuery:**

`$elem.height();` - gives height of the element without padding , border and margin

`$elem.innerHeight();` - gives height including padding

`$elem.outerHeight(true);` - gives height including padding, border and margin

**EDIT:**

If you want to find the height of the element before it is rendered , then i can give you one of many possible solutions

1. Append the element to the body with respective innerHTML's
2. Find the height using any of the above methods
3. Now,remove the element and of course , you found the height & element is not there

See Fiddle :[To get an element's rendered height](http://jsfiddle.net/aryYf/)

Comment: `$elem.outerHeight(true);` gives height including margin !! `$elem.outerHeight();` gives till border.

Answer (score 2):

**jQuery**

```
var height = $('.content').height();
console.log(height);
```

**Vanilla JS**

```
var height = document.getElementsByTagName('content').offsetHeight
console.log(height);
```

Answer (score 2):

### .height()

> Description: Get the current computed height.

[image]

- [`.height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) - jQuery API Documentation

---

### .innerHeight()

> Description: Get the current computed height, including padding but not border.

[image]

- [`.innerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/innerHeight/) - jQuery API Documentation

---

### .outerHeight()

> Description: Get the current computed height, including padding, border, and optionally margin.

- [`.outerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/) - jQuery API Documentation

Comment: there are more than 3 options

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery: `height` will give the height without border or padding, `innerHeight` gives the height including padding but without border and `outerHeight` gives height with border and padding with the option to include margin as well.

I vanillaJS, as Prasath K pointed out, `offsetHeight` will give you the height including padding and border.

There isn't really a way to calculate height of an element that is not in the dom. You can add it somewhere in the dom, calculate the height using one of the above methods and then remove it again.

Comment: but how do I tell the width? this is actually even before the view is rendered

Comment: i thought that you wanted to find the height after the view has been rendered.

Comment: No this is before the view is rendered

Comment: why do you have to know beforehand?

Answer (score 1):

Also, the answers here forget to mention the `scrollHeight` property, which can be used to get the full height of a DIV (all the scrollable content inside).

To call it, you need to use an index like that:

```
$('#content')[0].scrollHeight;
```

Comment: indeed a div built on it's contents only has offsetHeight of 1. many thanks my friend @Aerodynamika.

Answer (score 0):

Try like .**height()** like

```
var div_hght = $('.content').height();
alert(div_hght);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the techniques described above, in order to not have the element on screen when calculating, you can use `visibility: hidden` (CSS). You can't usually use `display: none`, because the element is usually considered to have no dimensions in that state.

You could also render to a div positioned below some obscuring element, using a negative `z-index`.